# AutoMapper for nested item collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I have models below:

```
public class Order
{
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order_OrderItem> Order_OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class Order_OrderItem
{
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderItem OrderItem { get; set; }
}
```

And I create DTO below:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OrderItemDto> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

How could I map `Order` to `OrderDto`?

I got error with below:

```
configuration.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(desc => desc.OrderItems,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Order_OrderItems));
```

I checked other related issues, and suggestions are related with map property from one to another, but my `OrderItems` is a collection property. How could I map it?

Any help would be appreciated.

## Update

Change configuration like below:

```
configuration.CreateMap<Order_OrderItem, OrderItemDto>();
configuration.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(desc => desc.OrderItems,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Order_OrderItems));
```

The `OrderItems` in `OrderDto` will be `null` when checking the result:

```
var result = ObjectMapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```

Comment: what error did you get? if you define a map(Order_OrderItem, OrderItemDto), the collection should be mapped correclty

Comment: @Jota.Toledo thanks, I added Order_OrderItem to OrderItemDto, and there is no error now, but the OrderItems property has null values for the properties. I assume it is caused that there is no corresponding properteis in Order_OrderItem, and the properties are in Order_OrderItem.OrderItem

Comment: I would suggest you to make use of  `AssertConfigurationIsValid` so that you get more detailed information about the validity of your config

Comment: where is your OrderItemDto mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map from `OrderItem` to `OrderItemDto`:

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemDto>();
```

Map from `Order` to `OrderDto`:

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderItems,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Order_OrderItems.Select(o => o.OrderItem)));
```